# Plug-in for Smart Search on Joomla: no results

Tags: search, plugins, joomla, components

I'm writing a plug-in for my component. For this component I have table "#__radiocatalog_item" with columns `id`, `name`, `description`, and I need to lookup at column `name`. For this, I wrote this plugin:

```
<?php

defined('JPATH_BASE') or die;

require_once JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR.'/components/com_finder/helpers/indexer/adapter.php';

class PlgFinderRadioitem extends FinderIndexerAdapter
{
   protected $context = 'Radioitem';
   protected $extension = 'com_radiocatalog';
   protected $layout = 'item';
   protected $type_title = 'item';
   protected $table = '#__radiocatalog_item';
   protected $state_field = 'parent';
   protected $autoloadLanguage = true;

   protected function setup()
        {
           return true;
        }


   public function onFinderDelete($context, $table)
   {
      if ($context == 'com_radiocatalog.item')
      {
         $id = $table->id;
      }
      elseif ($context == 'com_finder.index')
      {
         $id = $table->id;
      }
      else
      {
         return true;
      }

      return $this->remove($id);
   }

   public function onFinderChangeState($context, $pks, $value)
   {
      if ($context == 'com_radiocatalog.item')
      {
         $this->itemStateChange($pks, $value);
      }

      if ($context == 'com_plugins.plugin' && $value === 0)
      {
         $this->pluginDisable($pks);
      }
   }

   protected function index(FinderIndexerResult $item, $format = 'html')
   {
      if (JComponentHelper::isEnabled($this->extension) == false)
      {
         return;
      }

      $item->url = $this->getURL($item->id, 'com_radiocatalog&layout=item', $this->layout);
      $item->route = 'index.php?option=com_radiocatalog&view=item&layout=item&id='.$item->id;
      $item->addTaxonomy('Type', 'Radioitems');
      $item->addTaxonomy('Language', $item->language);
      $this->indexer->index($item);      
   }

   protected function getListQuery($sql = null)
   {
      $db = JFactory::getDbo();
      $sql = $sql instanceof JDatabaseQuery ? $sql : $db->getQuery(true);
      $sql->select('a.id as id, a.name as title, a.description as description');
      $sql->from('#__radiocatalog_item AS a');

      return $sql;
   }

   protected function getStateQuery()
   {
      $sql = $this->db->getQuery(true);
      $sql->select($this->db->quoteName('a.id'));
      $sql->select($this->db->quoteName('a.name').' as title');
      $sql->from($this->db->quoteName('#__radiocatalog_item') . ' AS a');
      return $sql;
   }
}
?>
```

After full indexing, search on the site does not work.

Comment: Two questions: 1. what version of Joomla and 2. What does happen after indexing & then searching? Do you see any errors?

Comment: I find it really unlikely that you would have a state field named parent.

Comment: @cppl 1. Joomla 3.2.0; 2. No visible errors;

Comment: @Elin This variable are not used :)

Comment: That variable is most certainly used by smart search.

Comment: @Elin, I'm add to table `publish` with default value 1, and update all. No results

Comment: Is the indexing putting data from your component into the finder tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was struggling with the same problem. So I enabled Joomla debugging {Global Configuration / System / Debug System = true} and tried to search for a term "myterm" using public site SmartSearch module. Then I checked the performed SQL queries. First, the term was found:

```
SELECT t.term, t.term_id
FROM j_finder_terms AS t
WHERE t.term = 'myterm' 
AND t.phrase = 0
```

with ID=653 (used later):

```
SELECT l.link_id,m.weight AS ordering
FROM `j_finder_links` AS l
INNER JOIN `j_finder_links_terms2` AS m 
ON m.link_id = l.link_id
WHERE l.access IN (1,1) 
AND l.state = 1 
AND (l.publish_start_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR l.publish_end_date <= '2014-01-04 17:34:00') 
AND (l.publish_end_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' OR l.publish_end_date >= '2014-01-04 17:34:00') 
AND m.term_id IN (653)
```

But this query didn't return any result, because j_finder_links.access and j_finder_links.state values were set to 0 instead of 1.

So my suggest you to check the queries and if you have the same problem, try to change your query from getStateQuery() method or select "1 AS access, 1 AS state" in the getListQuery() query and leave the $state_field variable unset.

I'm sorry for a vague explanation, I don't know much about how the SmartSearch work, I'm just trying to make it work somehow with my component.